# Is performance different with running a single instance or several with replication set up?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

If I run a single query, for example, execute an algorithm, does it make a difference (performance-wise) whether I run it on a **single** instance, or if I have **several** instances with **replication** set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ***read*** queries, there is no difference in performance because the communication overhead between the main instance and replicas is not measurable in most cases. For ***write*** queries that are modifying a lot of objects, the communication might have a measurable overhead if you use the **SYNC** mode. However, you can avoid this by using **ASYNC** mode, in which the main instance can commit a transaction without waiting for the replica to confirm that it received the transaction.

[Here](https://memgraph.com/blog/implementing-data-replication) is a post with detailed information about Memgraph's replication feature.